# VersionOverrides in manifest breaks excel add-in on Excel desktop but not 365

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am trying to create an add-in for excel, and everything works great with excel online, however when trying to make it work for excel desktop, it only works when commenting out all the markup in VersionOverrides. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>889d898d-86a1-4489-b156-b61bee7ffa11</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>SourceWhale</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="SourceWhale Add-In Testing"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2rorwy0vdjaw6cr/32.png?dl=0"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/uftjc9ztis7r2yp/64.png?dl=0"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://sourcewhale.app/dashboard"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://sourcewhale.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
      <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.3"/>
   </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="SourceWhale Button">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://res.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,f_auto,q_auto:eco,dpr_1/qksbdyt3lus5cs8k1amh"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://res.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,f_auto,q_auto:eco,dpr_1/qksbdyt3lus5cs8k1amh"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://res.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,f_auto,q_auto:eco,dpr_1/qksbdyt3lus5cs8k1amh"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812"/>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="SourceWhale has been added successfully!"/>
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="SourceWhale"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="SourceWhale"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Go to the HOME tab and click on the SourceWhale logo to get started."/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to open the SourceWhale Add-In"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

The addin works perfectly fine when it's commented out, but misses the features exposed by the overrides, and just commenting isn't a good solution because ideally it would work on both, but with the best features possible.

My excel is the most up to date 365 subscription version.

Comment: What is your version of Excel installed on the desktop?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Version 16.59 of excel for mac. It also does the exact same thing on my Windows PC Excel.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that on the desktop version of Excel, the URL to the images has to be in a certain form. Changing this fixed all my issues